# Apache Nifi - RouteOnAttribute "No Expression Found"

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an ExtractText processor where I've added 3 expressions: balance, card and name. To extract these values I am using regular expressions. So for name, I have the parsed portion of the incoming stream that looks like this: (.*?),\d+,\d+(?:.\d+)?  I have 2 PutKafka processors, 1 that accepts valid entries (matched) and one that accepts invalid entries (unmatched). So far, so good.

I wanted to add a specific test on a match, using the RouteOnAttribute processor against the name expression. The error I see is: 'name' validated against $(name:equals("CODE-01")} is invalid because No Expression Found. I think I have an expression. I obviously don't! :) Where did I take a wrong turn?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the first ( to { in your expression.

name property expression would be

> ${name:equals("CODE-01")}

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. I've been staring at this, bypassing the syntax--thinking there is something else I've missed. I appreciate the time you took to look at this @7632695 !

Comment: Working like a charm now! :) Thanks again agent @7632695!